# Why value is viewing with [] in grails view

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I am calling an action by remoteFunction for showing some value in some field.The value is viewing but with in []. I have no idea why it is behaving like this. Can anyone please help me on this please ? I am using grails 2.1.0. here are my attempts below :

my remoteFunction >>

```
<g:remoteFunction action="setValueForDetails"  params="'procurementMasterId='+procurementMasterId" update="changedValue"/>
```

my action in controller >>

```
def setValueForDetails(){
    def otmIFQDetailsByProcurementMaster
    if(params.procurementMasterId != null && params.procurementMasterId != "" && params.procurementMasterId != "null"){
       otmIFQDetailsByProcurementMaster = commonService.getOtmIFQDetailsValueByProcurementMaster(Long.parseLong(params.procurementMasterId))
    }
    render (template: 'ifqDetails', model: [otmIFQDetailsByProcurementMaster: otmIFQDetailsByProcurementMaster])
}
```

my field where I want to set the value in template >>

```
<g:textField id="PROCUREMENT_TYPE" name="PROCUREMENT_TYPE.id" readonly="" value="${otmIFQDetailsByProcurementMaster?.PROCUREMENT_TYPE}" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: `[element]` normally means it is a list with one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the 'PROCUREMENT_TYPE" is an Array of enums due to spelling, and displaying. So if You want to 'print' value without square brackets, You should change value to (if You want only first result):

```
value="${otmIFQDetailsByProcurementMaster?.PROCUREMENT_TYPE[0]}"
```

or if You want to should more than one element from list:

```
value="${otmIFQDetailsByProcurementMaster?.PROCUREMENT_TYPE.toString().replace('[', '').replace(']', '')}"
```

or simply iterate through the elements of PROCUREMENT_TYPE and show as many textfield as many PROCUREMENT_TYPE values You have.

Comment: thanks for your answere. It works ok but why 'PROCUREMENT_TYPE" is an Array of enums ?!! when I print the list by each method it prints the value without the [] in controller but in view why it shows [] ???

Comment: The only option is this, that you treated it like an array, for example You add element to 'PROCUREMENT_TYPE by .add().. or << or You didn't specify the type of PROCUREMENT_TYPE and it is set dynamically.